# How to obtain up to date information on hiking trails in Slovenia (Triglav National Park)?

Tags: hiking, preparation, trails

I am planning on a multi-day hike in Triglav National Park, staying at a different hut every night.

While researching a route I found that some trail sections [can be closed](https://stanje-poti.pzs.si/en.php), e.g.:
[image]

I found [another site with all trails](https://mapzs.pzs.si/) and there similar indications are given for that trail (albeit with additional sections marked as closed):
[image]

The following Slovenian text accompanies the last map:

> Closed sections on the trail:
> **Pod zahtevnim - Nad zahtevnim**
> 22.08.2021 Zaradi poškodovanih varoval je odsek planinske poti med sedlom Mlinarica in sedlom Planja do nadaljnjega ZAPRT.
> **Nad zahtevnim - Sedlo Planja**
> 22.08.2021 Zaradi poškodovanih varoval je odsek planinske poti med sedlom Mlinarica in sedlom Planja do nadaljnjega ZAPRT.
> **Koroška Rinka - Križ**
> 26.07.2017 Pot je do nadaljnjega zaprta zaradi poškodovanih varoval.
> **Mlinarica - Pod zahtevnim**
> 22.08.2021 Zaradi poškodovanih varoval je odsek planinske poti med sedlom Mlinarica in sedlom Planja do nadaljnjega ZAPRT.

While the dates presumably indicate when the closure was issued, it's not clear to me if the closure is still in effect.

Would anybody know a reliable way of checking if the trail is still closed?

Comment: Could you email one of the huts along the route?  They should have the most up-to-date information.

Answer (score 2):

After the e-mail suggestion I looked around for e-mail addresses and stumbled upon the following:

[image]

Apparently every closure has an associated alpine club that is responsible for it.

I've e-mailed them. It turns out they also manage a hut in the vicinity of that trail. They mentioned:

> ... the trail is indeed closed, but quite a few of our guest have taken that trail despite its closure.

What that means for safely being able to walk the trail is unclear, but the answer to my question is: contact the alpine club that is in charge of the closure. You can find the alpine club if you click on the closure icon (not the black trail line) on the [map with all trail closures](https://stanje-poti.pzs.si/en.php).